# Autolayout set min height for content in UITableViewCell for iOS 7 and iOS 8

Tags: uitableview, autolayout

I create `UITableViewCell` with two `UILabels` like title and subtitle. This `UITableViewCell` has dynamic height. When title and subtitle have one line I want `UITableViewCell` height to be equal 44.0. But I get less.

Code:

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    [self.labelTitle autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(6.0, 16.0, 6.0, 8.0) excludingEdge:ALEdgeBottom];
    [self.labelDetailedTitle autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(6.0, 16.0, 6.0, 8.0) excludingEdge:ALEdgeTop];
    [self.labelTitle autoPinEdge:ALEdgeBottom toEdge:ALEdgeTop ofView:self.labelDetailedTitle];
return self;
```

}

Is it possible some how to set min height for `UITableViewCell` content?

Comment: yes it is possible but can you give details of how you have created you cell.